# How to use a function in string formatting in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm loading a JSON and I'm printing string formatting.

```
fmt = (u"{id:<4} {title:<28} {timestamp:<23} {description:<23}"
       u" {link}")
```

and to print:

```
for item in items
    print(fmt.format(**item))
```

This works fine. But the problem here is that I'm printing a unix timestamp.

Now I've written a function (`convert_unix_timestamp`)which converts the unix timestamp to a readable timestamp.

But how can I use this function and also use my string formatting?

I was thinking about something as below but I don't know how to make this work

```
fmt = (u"{id:<4} {title:<28} {self.convert_unix_timestamp(timestamp):<23} {description:<23}"
       u" {link}")
```

Can someone tell me how I can use a function inside this above?

Comment: This isn't a click question. You pass the result of `str.format()` to click, this is a *string formatting* question.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax for what is possible with the syntax.

Comment: In this case, just update the dictionary first, or copy the dictionary and then update the value with the function.

Comment: If you are using Python 3.6, use [formated string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) instead.

Comment: Also, if this really is Python 3 as your question tag suggests, then the `u` prefixes to the string literals are redundant. They are only needed in Python 2 or code that needs to remain compatible with Python 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks I'll try to use the formated string literals! And yes, I used python 2.7 a bit in the past, this is the first time I'm trying 3.6, so making some silly mistakes.

Comment: Although, you are using a format string in a variable; `f` strings produce the formatted result when executed, not via a separate `.format()` method call.  If you need to be able to swap out format strings then an `f` string won’t be suitable.